# Initializing static class members - some clarification please

Tags: java, static, initialization

I'm a bit of a novice with java and I would appreciate some clarification on when static class variables need to initialized.  It a bit much to insert the code I have, so let me break it down to the essential elements. I have an object that performs a particular task.  This task requires a number of parameters to be set.  These parameters would ideally be static as any instance of the class would use the same parameters.  The object is basically a robot that automates a task. The first instance of the robot must be "trained" to do the task (guided by user input).  In this "training" it learns a few key parameters and, from those, calculates others that are needed (via a private method).  The key parameters are then saved to file to be used by other instances and with subsequent runs of the program (i.e. training is done once only).

The code is structured something like this...

```
public class Master {
   static int[] keyPara;
   static int[] otherPara;

   public Master() {
      /* some defining stuff */
   }

   void doGuidedTask() {
       /* some stuff that calls private methods, etc */
   }

   void doTask() {
      /* some stuff that calls private methods etc */
   }

   void calcOtherPara() {
      /* method to calculate other parameters given key parameters */
   }

   void saveKeyPara() {
      /* method to save key parameters to File */
   }
}
```

The question is what is the proper/best way to initialize these parameters in code?  keyPara are determined by implementing the doGuidedTask method, and otherPara are found using the calcOtherPara method.  After a single implementation of doGuidedTask, saveKeyPara can be invoked to save them to file and can be read in for subsequent runs of the application program.

I could use a static initialization block: test if the file exists, if so load the key parameters.  Not sure if this is allowed because it will require the use of the calcOtherPara method to determine the other parameters i.e. its using a class method in the initialization.  Even the read in keyPara would be best implemented as a method (with an eye for future development of the code).  The same problem arises if I use the same approach in the constructor - I read elsewhere in the forum that using methods within the constructor is not recommended (not sure I understood why exactly).

I read the tutorial on static variables but it really was not clear to me exactly when they need to be defined and what I should be doing in this case.  Any advice here would be appreciated.

Comment: I think calcOtherPara and saveKeyPara could be defined static too, as (if I have understood your program) they will access only static variables. So you could call then inside static initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Master {
    static boolean initialised=false;
    static int[] keyPara;
    static int[] otherPara;

    public void doTask() {
        if (!initialised)
        {
            boolean filefound=false;
            // put here code to check if your saved file exists
            if(filefound)
            {
               loadkeyfile();
               calcOtherPara();
               initialised=true;
               doAutomatedTask();
            } else {
               doGuidedTask();
               saveKeyPara();
               calcOtherPara();
               initialised=true;
            }
        } else {
            doAutomatedTask();
        }
    } 
    private void doAutomatedTask() {
       // put your non-interactive version here
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what I had in mind.  Just to be clear: in this case the static variables will not be initialized until an instance is created and doTask is initiated - I take it this is ok?

Comment: correct. Since you say you are novice this is an acceptable solution. Once you learn more about object orientation and design patterns you can start thinking of splitting things op using a factory or builder pattern. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a static method to initialize static variables.

You can call this static method from the static initializer of the class.

```
static {
   staticMethodThatInitializesStaticMembers ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that are trying to implement something before your object model design is complete. You may have the following objects: `Robot` (the thing that performs a task); `Task` (the thing to be performed); `TaskStrategy` (how to perform the task .. the item you talk about having guided and calculated parameters).  You will need to determine whether your task strategies are by task or by robot, and including a reference to a `TaskStrategy` object in the appropriate class. You may want a `TaskStrategyLibrary` that handles the task strategies from initial creation through successive learning cycle.  With a factory class you can get the appropriate task strategy for a robot (`strategy = TaskStrategyLibrary.getStrategy(Robot, Task)`;  and have the TaskStrategy class handle "parameter" changes and update of base strategy.

Answer (score -1):

For this example, I would recommend initializing them when you declare them. So for example, you'd do this:

```
static int[] keyPara = {1, 2, 3, 4}; //put your array here
static int[] otherPara = {1, 2, 3, 4}; //put a different (or the same) array here
```